# Ajax Search with ' in query

Tags: javascript

I have a field where a user can search for a name and the according fields will be shown:

```
$('.search').keyup(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        delay(function(){
            if(name != ""){
                $('[data-load]').parent().hide(function(){
                    $("[data-name^="+name+"]").parent().parent().fadeIn();
                });
            }
            if(champ == ""){
                $('[data-load]').parent().show();
            }
        }, 1000 );
    });

    var delay = (function(){
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();
```

That only works if the user does not search for a name like "O'Hara", that breaks the javascript:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-name^=O']
```

What is the correct way to enable a search for those names?

Answer (score 2):

When using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) like `[attrName ^= attrValue]`,

> Attribute values must be CSS [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or [strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

In the example, `O'Hara` should be escaped to `O\'Hara`, `"O'Hara"` or `'O\'Hara'`.

In general, identifiers are much more restrictive than strings, so if you use them you will need to escape lots of characters. Therefore, I recommend using strings, that is, enclosing the value with single or double quotes. The value of a string can be everything, with those limitations:

- > Double quotes cannot occur inside double quotes, unless escaped (e.g.,
  >   as `'\"'` or as `'\22'`). Analogously for single quotes (e.g., `"\'"` or
  >   `"\27"`).
- > A string cannot directly contain a newline. To include a newline in a
  >   string, use an escape representing the line feed character in
  >   ISO-10646 (U+000A), such as `"\A"` or `"\00000a"`.
- The backslash (`\`) is used as a escaping character. So a literal backslash must be escaped.

Therefore, you can use

```js
$("[data-name ^= '"
   + name.replace(/["'\\]/g, '\\$&').replace(/\n/g, '\\a ')
+ "']")
```

```js
var name = "0a\"b'c\\d\ne";
document.querySelector(
  "[data-name ^= '"
    + name.replace(/["'\\]/g, '\\$&').replace(/\n/g, '\\a ')
  + "']"
).style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div data-name="0a&quot;b'c\d
ef">I should be blue</div>
```

Or, if your browser supports it, you can use [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.escape)

```js
$("[data-name ^= " + CSS.escape(name) + "]")
```

```js
var name = "0a\"b'c\\d\ne";
document.querySelector("[data-name ^= " + CSS.escape(name) + "]")
.style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div data-name="0a&quot;b'c\d
ef">I should be blue</div>
```

Comment: What happens the user types a double-quote?

Comment: @RichieHindle Then they must be escaped with ``\``. I included it in my answer, thanks.